tensorflowjs model prediction gives NaN
I created a model in tensorflowjs, it takes a csv file with coordinate data, for example values between -0.5 and 0.5. It has 99 features and 2 classes punch and no punch.
Here is the code for that creates it, I was able to download 2 files from the browser, model.json and model.weights.bin:
document.getElementById('csvFileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);

async function handleFileSelect(event) {
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    const data = await parseCSV(file);
    trainModel(data);
}

async function parseCSV(file) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const data = [];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const lines = reader.result.split('\n');
            for (const line of lines) {
                const values = line.trim().split(',');
                const label = values.shift();
                const coordinates = values.map(parseFloat);
                data.push({ label, coordinates });
            }
            resolve(data);
        };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsText(file);
    });
}

async function trainModel(data) {
    const features = data.map(entry => entry.coordinates);
    const labels = data.map(entry => entry.label === 'punch' ? 0 : 1);

    const model = tf.sequential({
        layers: [
            tf.layers.dense({ inputShape: [99], units: 64, activation: 'relu' }),
            tf.layers.dense({ units: 2, activation: 'softmax' })
        ]
    });

    model.compile({
        optimizer: 'adam',
        loss: 'sparseCategoricalCrossentropy',
        metrics: ['accuracy']
    });

    await model.fit(tf.tensor2d(features), tf.tensor1d(labels), { epochs: 10 });

    console.log('Model trained successfully.');

    // Save model to the models directory
    await model.save('downloads://model');

    console.log('Model saved successfully.');
}



Then I tried to test the model.json file with test data like so
async function testModel() {
    const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('./models/model.json');

    const inputTensor = tf.tensor2d(new Array(99).fill(0.5), [1, 99]);
    console.log("Inputtensor: ", inputTensor)

    console.log("Inputtensor shape: ", inputTensor.shape);

    console.log("Inputtensor datasync: " ,inputTensor.dataSync()); 

    const prediction = model.predict(inputTensor);

    prediction.print(); 
}

in the console in chrome after printing everything I got this:
Inputtensor:  e {kept: false, isDisposedInternal: false, shape: Array(2), dtype: 'float32', size: 99, …}
model_test.js:7 Inputtensor shape:  (2) [1, 99]
model_test.js:9 Inputtensor datasync:  Float32Array(99) [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, buffer: ArrayBuffer(396), byteLength: 396, byteOffset: 0, length: 99, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): 'Float32Array']
tfjs@latest:17
Tensor
[[NaN, NaN],]
I don't know why it gives me NaN in the prediction probabilities.

I am getting the exact same thing with my pre-trained weather prediction model. Any fixes?
